# Why does Smartsheet's updateRowsAllowPartialSuccess return a "Success" in its message when the rows on the sheet aren't updated?

Tags: java, smartsheet-api

I have an arrayList of Row objects and am using smartsheet's api to update the rows as shown below:

```
ArrayList<Row> updatingRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
/* 
  Logic to add desired rows
*/
PartialRowUpdateResult updatedRows = smartsheet.sheetResources().rowResources().updateRowsAllowPartialSuccess(longRepresentingMySheetID, 
            updatingRows);
```

When I use `System.out.println(updatedRows.getMessage())`, the console prints out SUCCESS. However, when I examine the sheet itself, there hasn't been an update, and the last edited date/time doesn't change either. I have made sure that I am using the correct sheet ID, so why am I getting a SUCCESS message when no updates are happening on the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message that you're seeing is actually just the Smartsheet API letting you know that the API request executed successfully, with no errors. It doesn't indicate that the row(s) in your request were updated.

For instance, if I send a row update request with the same cell values that are currently in the row, the response will return a `SUCCESS` message but the row cells will not update the cells, because the values didn't change.